# Can I make changes in inc folder script in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change some links some link from login button.

So how could I do this?

I got script where I can make changes i.e `wp-content/plugins/learnpress/inc/class-lp-shortcodes.php`

But is it the correct way of editing core scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Plugins are not part of Wordpress core scripts. 
There for you can feel safe changing them as you will, you can always turn them off from the admin panel.

You can use the Wordpress docs to learn more about ever thing you need - https://codex.wordpress.org/

Comment: if you update the plugin itself it will over ride your code, but if you just update the wordpress version it will not.

Comment: Ok. but how can make changes in these script that will not override after plugin updation. Is there any way to customize plugin as like theme customization by simply copying script to child theme directory?